# Cannot sign up Neo4j Desktop (possibly due to proxy)

Tags: neo4j, proxy

I get an error message when I try to sign up.

```
WE'RE SORRY, SOMETHING WENT WRONG WHEN ATTEMPTING TO SIGN UP. PLEASE CHECK YOUR INTERNET CONNECTION
```

I'm on the desktop version for windows 10.

My company has a proxy setup that often causes problems... Does anyone know if I can configure Neo4j to use the proxy? Thanks in advance.

Edit. Cheers for the downvotes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the log via github account option and it works.